# Remove lowest integer from list using for loops

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

I am trying out a coding challenge and am getting stuck.
The idea is to find the lowest integer in a `List<int>` and return a new list with that value removed but retaining the original order.
I am trying to do this using only a `for` loop.

The problem I am having is that as I iterate over and compare each value to the other values, my end result only comes out the last instance where one number was less than the other, not necessarily the lowest number.

For instance if I pass in `List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` the result comes back as 4.

I realise it would be easier to use `Min` and `Remove` (or alike) on a duplicated list, but I am purposely trying to make life hard for myself.

```
public static List<int> RemoveSmallest(List<int> numbers)
        {
            var newList = new List<int>();
            var lowest = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i <= numbers.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (var n = 0; n <= numbers.Count - 1; n++)
                {
                    if (numbers[i] < numbers[n])
                    {
                        lowest = numbers[i];
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var num in numbers)
            {
                if (num != lowest)
                {
                    newList.Add(num);
                }
            }

            newList.Remove(lowest);
            return newList;
        }
```

Comment: firslty,you don't need a nested loop.

Comment: Care to expand on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code closest to yours that fixes your problem:

```
public static List<int> RemoveSmallest(List<int> numbers)
{
    var newList = new List<int>();

    if (numbers != null && numbers.Count > 0)
    {
        var lowest = numbers[0];

        for (var i = 1; i < numbers.Count; i++)
        {
            if (numbers[i] < lowest) {
                lowest = numbers[i];
            }
        }

        foreach (var num in numbers)
        {
            if (num != lowest)
            {
                newList.Add(num);
            }
        }
    }
    return newList;
}
```

**EDIT:** Since there were some concerns in the comments I added a check if the list is empty to the code.

Comment: If you pass the list OP uses in the question as sample input it will return the exact same list, without anything removed (none of the numbers there are lower than 0)

Comment: @UnholySheep Yup, I fixed it.

Comment: @john It's working fine this side. I added a check for an empty list too

Comment: "Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Comment: What happens if the List is null? What happens is the List has no members in the array? This isn't safe code at all.

Comment: @alexc95 I personally don't think that code examples that address a specific question need to be production ready with all possible checks. But does it look better to you now?

Comment: @BenjaminKrupp I hope you're joking. If you provide people with code you should provide code that works in production. Admittedly, it would be silly to take code and paste it straight into production, but this doesn't mean you have to be lazy and post code that is unsafe just because you think that people won't use it in production.

Comment: OP: "I am trying out a coding challenge and am getting stuck." Context always matters.

Comment: @alexc95 Also even in my first unsave version I added a warning. So I don't get the danger here.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
public static List<int> RemoveSmallest(List<int> numbers)
{
    if (numbers == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("numbers");
    }

    if (numbers.Count > 1)
    {
        int smallest = numbers[0];
        int smallestIdx = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (numbers[i] < smallest)
            {
                smallest = numbers[i];
                smallestIdx = i;
            }
        }
        return new List<int>(numbers.Where((value, index) => index != smallestIdx));
    }
    else
    {
        return new List<int>(0);
    }
}
```

Note that numbers.Where() is basically performing a second while loop through all the numbers, so complexity is 2O(n), i.e. O(n).

Answer (score -1):

Asumming the lowest item is not repeated, you can store the index of the lowest item in a variable.

```
public static List<int> RemoveSmallest(List<int> numbers)
{
    var lowestIndex = -1;
    var lowest = Int32.MaxValue;

    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] < lowest) {
            lowest = numbers[i];
            lowestIndex = i;
        }
    }

    var newList = new List<int>(numbers);
    newList.RemoveAt(lowestIndex);

    return newList;
```

}

Comment: OP: "I realise it would be easier to use Min and Remove (or alike) on a duplicated list, but I am purposely trying to make life hard for myself."

Comment: This will throw a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` with the sample input provided in the question

Comment: You probably want to set "lowest" to int.MaxValue

Comment: Corrected, initial value should be greater

Comment: You don't set the lowest to int.MaxValue or int.MinValue, you just set it to the first item in the array. See my answer.

Comment: * To clarify my comment, try this test set: `new List<int>() { 5, 6, 3, int.MaxValue, int.MinValue, -10, 8 };`

Answer (score -2):

though it is not wrong to use nested loops, you can accomplish it without. Basically, you can treat the first element within the list as the smallest prior to iteration, then traverse through the list to check if there is any other number smaller than the one already selected, if that is the case then update the `lowest` variable appropriately and proceed down the list.

full solution here:

```
public static List<int> RemoveSmallest(List<int> numbers)
{

       if(numbers == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("null argument");
       if (numbers.Count < 1) return numbers;

       var newList = new List<int>();
       var lowest = numbers[0]; // treat this as the smallest

       for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Count; i++)
       {
            if (numbers[i] < lowest) // compare it against other elements
            {
                lowest = numbers[i]; // update lowest
            }

       }

       foreach (var num in numbers)
       {
            if (num != lowest)  // dont add the lowest
            {
                newList.Add(num);
            }
       }

       return newList;
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the same answer as [Benjamin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43542306/2541501). You've only added short text explanation and `if (numbers.Count < 1) return numbers;` I think this would be better suited as a comment or an edit on Benjamin's answer.

Comment: That's still two loops.

Comment: @john my comment said "nested loops"

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw No it didn't. Nice [editing after the fact](http://imgur.com/a/CvdNa) though.

Comment: @john Ousmane was referring to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542232/remove-lowest-integer-from-list-using-for-loops#comment74136274_43542232).

Comment: @PJvG I didn't realise you had commented, too. Sorry for suggesting you were anything but a gentleman.